# Could anyone explain why is the article used before percentage? Is there any grammatical rule regarding this?

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-article, numbers, countability

Could anyone explain why is the article used before percentage? Is there any grammatical rule regarding this?

1. Most countries would be very happy with **a** 7% growth in this environment. [Link](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.timesofindia.com/business/india-business/india-can-tap-china-plus-1-window-to-create-manufacturing-jobs-world-bank-president-ajay-banga/amp_articleshow/101970892.cms)
2. But analysts expect the growth to slow, amid **a** 12.4% slump in exports in the second quarter. [link2](https://www.google.com/amp/s/m.economictimes.com/news/international/business/chinas-economy-grew-6-3-on-year-in-second-quarter-official-data/amp_articleshow/101809751.cms)
3. The company reported total revenue of $667.5 million for the fourth quarter of 2022, **a** 12.3 percent increase from a year earlier.
4. Subscriptions accounted for $414.1 million, **a** 17.9 percent increase. [link3](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/02/08/business/media/new-york-times-earnings.html)

Comment: I think it would be better either as "happy with a 7% growth rate" or as "happy with 7% growth".

Comment: That is just Indian English as used in The Times of India.

Comment: @Lambie Is that why there are thousands and thousands of examples of such constructions in COCA?

Comment: **a 7% growth rate**, sure. But not just **a 7% growth**   Also, **7% growth**, without a. The thing is one either has these things internalized or not. Who needs to look these up?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>The term '7%' is, of course, pronounced as 'seven percent'. I shall use the words instead or symbols in the rest of this post.</sup>

Phrases like *seven percent*  can be used in many different ways in a sentence. For example:

1. Inflation rose by seven percent.
2. Seven percent is a very high interest rate for a mortgage.
3. We got a seven percent raise.
4. This drink is seven percent water.

In (1) we see the phrase functioning as Complement of a preposition. In (2) it is the Subject of the sentence. In both (3) and (4) it functions as an Attributive Modifier of a noun. This is the same function that an attributive adjective would have:

5. We got a [**big** raise].
6. This drink is [**pure** water].

Now if you have a look at (5) and (6), you might wonder why there is an article, *a*, before the word *big* but not before the word *pure*. The reason, of course, is that we need an article in (5) because the singular countable noun *raise* needs an article (or other word in Determiner function). We don't need an article in (6) because the noun *water* is uncountable . We don't need to use an article or other Determiner with uncountable nouns like water. And it is ***ungrammatical*** to use the indefinite article *a* with an uncountable noun:

8. *A water was running down the window.
9. *An information is all we needed.

So the reason we have an article in (3) and not in (4) is for the same reason: *raise* is countable but *water* isn't.

**The Original Poster's question**

The reason that the writer has used an indefinite article in the noun phrases:

10. **a** 7% **growth**
11. **a** 12.4% **slump**
12. **a** 12.3% **increase**
13. **a** 17.9% **increase**

... is because the nouns in bold are all being used as singular countable nouns. Singular countable nouns in English must have a Determiner, for example: *a, the, no, my, any* and so forth.

---

**Grammar note:**

<sup>A trivial point here is that some writers might prefer to stick with *growth* as an uncountable noun here:</sup>

<sup>-  Most countries would be very happy with 7% growth in this environment.</sup>

<sup>This is what a couple of the commenters have mentioned below the question. One commenter speculates that this was peculiar to Indian English. However, this is in fact a very common, everyday, countable use of the word *growth*. It occurs very, very frequently in standard British and US English in scholarly publication and on the news and so forth.</sup>

<sup>Here are some examples from COCA (the Corpus of Contemporary American English):</sup>

<sup>- [R]etailers expect only a 4 percent growth in sales.</sup>
<sup>- [W]ith a 4 percent growth, it's beginning to see light at the end of its economic tunnel.</sup>
<sup>- The best this economy will ever do is a 3 percent growth per year.</sup>
<sup>- [W]hat you will see next year is something on the order of a 3 percent growth in domestic product.</sup>

Comment: Neither of your last two commented dictionary examples uses an indefinite article.

Comment: or *I, too, think it is important to open futures markets which cover, as far as possible all growths of cotton*]

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, I was choosing the wrong ones.

Comment: "a 7% growth
... is that when used in this sense, the noun growth can be countable." Huh?? I had some growths removed from my back. Growth is unaccountable in terms of economic growth. Never countable. Of course, growths of cotton but not economic growths for heaven's sake.

Comment: @Lambie Merriam Webster: *a growth of wealth*. Or look at the other examples for COCA in the post. Or look at the many hundreds of examples of *an X% growth* in COCA itself. Doesn't take a minute.

Comment: As @Lambie, the commented example isn't the same use of *growth*. Here it is more like *plantations*.

Comment: @WeatherVane The *growths in cotton* doesn't refer to plantations, it refers to 'growths' in the cotton market!

Comment: It depends very much on context. You've given a raft of examples but no clear answer. You did not even abide by its first sentence.

Comment: @WeatherVane The answer's very clear: the article depends on the noun not the modifier. What's not to understand?

Comment: For the past five years the international trade in raw cotton of all growths has averaged about 12 1/2 million bales annually.

Of this volume, the United States has furnished a little over 5 million bales.
Today, the war has effectively eliminated as importers of cotton practically the entire Continent of Europe, consuming about 5 millions of bales annually of all growths of cotton. http://www.ibiblio.org/pha/policy/1940/1940-06-27a.html growths here means like "harvests". Not growth in the cotton market. growths with an s is NEVER used like that in economics.

Comment: @Lambie If someone says that some people have black hair, there's no point brining up an example of a person with red hair and presenting it as a counter-argument. And Merriam Webster, and Cambridge , and COCA all produce examples which disprove the idea that *growth*, referring to economic things, is never used countably. For example, the cited *a growth of wealth* from Merriam Webster.

Comment: Yes, of course, a growth of wealth. **But not growths of wealth**.

Answer (score 0):

The grammatical 'rule' is that articles identify something as being either specific (eg *the* increase) or one of many (eg *an* increase).

They are correctly used in your examples because they refer to *periods* of increase or growth. So, you could refer to 'a' period, or 'the' specific period already identified. Worded differently, 'growth' can be a non-countable noun - for example, "*the country experienced growth of 7% last year*".

What may have more influence on your quotations than any grammatical rule is a *style guide*. Academic and media organisations usually have their own guidance to ensure *consistency* between writers, and the way numbers and percentages are expressed is often covered in such guides. I noticed that your quotations seemed pretty consistent in the way they express the percentage. In the UK, most media outlets seem to use "*per cent*" instead of the compound word "*percent*" or the percent mark. I usually take that as an indicator that a quotation has come from a newspaper.